# Javascript and RegEx: Split and keep delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, delimiter

I have a regex which will split my string into arrays.

Everyything works fine except that I would like to keep a part of the delimiter.

Here is my regex:

```
(&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;)[\s]
```

in Javascript, I am doing:

```
var test = paragraph.split(/(&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;)[\s]/g);
```

My paragraph is as followed:

```
Current addresses:  &dagger;    Biopharmaceutical Research and Development<br />
&Dagger;    Clovis Oncology<br />
&sect;  Pisces Molecular <br />
||  School of Biological Sciences    
&para;  Department of Chemistry<br />
```

The problem is that I am getting 10 elements in my array and not 5 as I should. In fact, I am also getting my delimiter as an element and my goal is to keep the delimiter with the splited element and not to create a new one.

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT:

I would like to get this as a result:

```
1. &dagger; Biopharmaceutical Research and Development<br />
2. &Dagger; Clovis Oncology<br />
3. &sect;   &sect;  Pisces Molecular <br />
||  School of Biological Sciences  
4.  &para;  Department of Chemistry<br />
```

Comment: [This has been asked before.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310725/javascript-split-include-delimiters)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Where ? I can't get the solution.

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't seen that it's a link.

Comment: are you trying to create a [template](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378001/36866)?

Comment: I sow already that post but I can't get the answer to my problem.

Comment: @some, not at all, I am only trying to parse some info from the paragraph

Comment: The top answer provides a RegEx that should solve your problem, and the other posters say that it's a Bad Idea (with capitals) to use RegEx on HTML.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, I can't make it work. My problem is that I am getting the delimiter as a new element and I don't know why. For the regex and html, in fact this is not realy an html, I am managing only <br />, nothing else.

Comment: If you're really just managing `<br />` elements then I might have a solution for you. If it ever gets more complicated though, my solution would fall apart.

Comment: Only <br /> and special characters can be in the HTML. My goal is to split the string in elements starting with special characters &xxxx; I can do it with my regx but the problem is that I am also catching the delimiter as a new element.

Comment: The reason you get 10 instead of five is: [ECMAScript262:5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) 15.5.4.14 "If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array."

Comment: Thank you @some, do you maybe have an idea on how to avoid that ?

Comment: Could you give an example of what result you want? I'm thinking of using `match` instead.

Comment: a.match(/&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;[^&]*/g);

Comment: Answered the same answer. Take a look:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18582159/721704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `match` instead:

```
var test = paragraph.match(/&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;\s[^&]*/g);
```

Updated: Added a required white-space `\s` match.

Explanation:

- `&#?` Match `&` and an optional `#` (the question mark match previous one or zero times)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` is a range of all upper and lower case characters and digits. If you also accept an underscore you could replace this with `\w`.
- The `+` sign means that it should match the last pattern one or more times, so it matches one or more characters a-z, A-Z and digits 0-9.
- The `;` matches the character `;`.
- The `\s` matches the class white-space. That includes space, tab and other white-space characters.
- `[^&]*` Once again a range, but since `^` is the first character the match is negated, so instead of matching the `&`-characters it matches everything but the `&`. The star matches the pattern zero or more times.
- `g` at the end, after the last `/` means `global`, and makes the `match` continue after the first match and get an array of all matches.

So, match `&` and an optional `#`, followed by any number of letters or digits (but at least one), followed by `;`, followed by a white-space, followed by zero or more characters that isn't `&`.

Comment: Thank you very much. If possible, can I also check if there is a space after the special character as a separator.

Comment: @Milos Do you want space (0x20) or any white-space (space, tab, form feed, line feed and other unicode spaces)?

Comment: Great, thank you very much, that's exactly what I need. If possible, could you please give me a little explanation on how works the regex you gived me. I know, I am wasting your time, sorry, but I would like to understand it, not only copy paste. :)

Comment: @Milos Excellent that you want to understand it! Tell me if something isn't clear.

Comment: Thank you veery much, that's a clear and efficient answer. I will try to get better inside of the RegEx. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Milos No problem! By the way, you can use [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) to play around with regexps and see in realtime what it matches.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, this solution (untested, by the way) will only work if you're just managing `<br />` elements. Here:

```
var text = paragraph.split("<br />"); // now text contains just the text on each line

for(var i = 0; i<text.length-1; i++) { // don't want to add an line break to our last line
    text[i] += " <br />"; // replace the <br /> elements on each line
}
```

The variable `text` is now an array, where each element of the array is a line of the original paragraph. The linebreaks (`<br />`) have been added back on the end of each line. You just mentioned that you want to split on the special characters, but from what I see, each line ends in a line break, so this should hopefully have the same effect. Unfortunately I don't have the time to write up a more complete answer at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you have misunderstood my question. I know how to split my with a special character as delimiter. We can forget the <br />. I only need to split the string in elements starting with special characters and keep tose special characters in the element.

Comment: I was afraid of that, as I didn't have much time to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex it is pretty simple:

```
var result = input.match(/&#?[^\W_]+;\s[^&]*/g);
```

#### Test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b6Y6Z/).